# Why do you need to use iTunes to delete photos?

Tags: iphone

I've asked a question about how to delete images on the iPhone 4s, but the delete button doesn't show up. I've seen on the internet that you need iTunes, why?

Comment: What photos are you trying to delete? I promise you that you don’t need iTunes to delete photos taken with a Canon camera and then transferred to a Windows PC and edited in Photoshop. What hardware and software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

- If the photos were taken on iPhone or transferred to iPhone, they can be deleted on iPhone.
- If the photos were synchronised with iPhone using iTunes they must be deleted with iTunes.

Comment: what @grg said, mostly. But on a Mac you delete the photos in the photo.app on a PC you delete the photos from the folder you are syncing with. Once that is done you sync your iPhone and the photos are removed. Yah that has annoyed me for years, but as they say Apple Must Have It's Reasons...